# file_put_contents not putting what I want

Tags: php

I searched for hours why my code doesn't work, in fact it does create a file but it's not filled with what it's supposed to be.

So here's an example :

- User enters a new password for the website, let's take `hugo` as a password.
- The php hashes it and then displays it for debugging : `hugo` becomes `f0a3e0cbd8776ace8d3069ce2942e9f1`.
- Then it does the file_put_contents to put the hashed string in the .txt file. But when I open this file via FTP, there's `3293ac630c13f0245f92bbb1766e1616` in it !

Even if I delete the file, whatever is the user input, this code is always written in the file, and this hashed strings means null (I have this same hashed code when I hash a null input).

If I run the same code without the hash function, it creates an empty file.

```
if ($action == "ch_mdp") {
    no_check_timer();
    if (htmlspecialchars($_POST["mdp"]) == htmlspecialchars($_POST["mdp2"])) {      
        $crypt = hash($algo, htmlspecialchars($_POST["mdp"]));
        echo $_POST["mdp"]." | ".$_POST["mdp2"]." | ".$crypt." | ./bdd/".$_SESSION["login"]."/mdp.txt";//DEBUG
        file_put_contents("./bdd/".$_SESSION["login"]."/mdp.txt", $crypt);
        echo "<p>Password changed.</p>";
        footer(true);
    } else {
        echo $_POST["mdp"]." | ".$_POST["mdp2"]." | ".$crypt." | ./bdd/".$_SESSION["login"]."/mdp.txt";
        echo "<p/><span class='erreur'>ERROR : password & pass confirmation do not match.</span><br/>";
        footer(true);
    }
}
```

There's no probem with `$_SESSION` and `$_POST` whitch actually contain what is expected

Comment: What is the value of `$algo`?

Comment: It's : 
$algo = "tiger128,3";

Comment: Is this absolute path? "./bdd/".$_SESSION["login"]."/mdp.txt"

Comment: Put absolute directory path and also check write permission of the file where you want to write file content.

Comment: *(offtopic)* Please use [password_hash](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) for storing passwords

Comment: No, that's the relative path from the php.

Comment: OK thanks I'll try it

Comment: @HetalChauhan this is not a problem with the file location as `OP` is able to see and open the written file

Comment: What is the result of `htmlspecialchars($_POST["mdp"])`? This is not in your debug output, it is possible for it to return an empty string. If the result is not empty, I'm almost tempted to think you may have an extra `file_put_contents()` somewhere in your code

Comment: Or, this code could also be executed even when the form was not submitted (I don't see a check for that in your code snippet) and `$_POST["mdp"]` does not exist.

Comment: var_dump($_POST["mdp"]); outputs : string(4) "hugo"

The code shows the form if $_GET["action"] == "profil" and executes the code above if it's equal to "ch_mdp"

Comment: Purely for testing: can you change it so that the `FILE_APPEND` flag is used? I'd like to know if the correct hash is written to the file and then immediately overwritten with the wrong hash.

Comment: Apologies, you were right :f0a3e0cbd8776ace8d3069ce2942e9f13293ac630c13f0245f92bbb1766e1616

Comment: Though I can't figure out why the code executes even if "if ($action == "ch_mdp")" is not true :/

Comment: There's nothing wrong with that `if` statement, could it be that there is a `file_put_contents()` on the same text file somewhere else in your code? Or maybe somewhere `$action` gets set to `"ch_mdp"` when it shouldn't be?

Comment: Just checked, there's only one "$action =" in the whole php file, and all other "file_put_contents" are in other if statements testing on $action. I can also modify this "if" in order to test both $action and $_POST not empty.

Comment: That's a good first step. If this code is (for some reason) executed when the form is not yet submitted, your `if` will also match (`$_POST["mdp"]` and `$_POST["mdp2"]` will *both* not exist, so their values are the same). Is `$action` also `"ch_mdp"` when you're simply *displaying* the form?

Comment: The form is displayed in a "if ($action =="profil") {", in fact if $_GET["action"] is not defined, $action will be null and then the "home page" is displayed. All different contents are displayed or executed under if statements.

Comment: Well, it works now. Thanks for your help !